# custom attribute works only with element.getAttribute("attribute") but not "element.attribute"

Tags: javascript, getattribute, custom-attribute

I have just noticed, that if I give a custom attribute to an html element, for example:

```
<input type="button" id="my_button" custom_attr="custom_attr_text" value="value_text" />
```

then i can retrieve it like this:

```
document.getElementById("my_button").getAttribute("custom_attr");
```

and it will return `"custom_attr_text"`, but if I do

```
document.getElementById("my_button").custom_attr;
```

then it returns `undefined`!

I also noticed that with a built in attribute (for example `value` or `id`) both of the above works fine!
Could somebody please explain why is this happening?

Comment: It's a littlebit jQuery-specific, but see the duplicate of [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr). If you want a only-plain-js explanation, see http://javascript.info/tutorial/attributes-and-custom-properties

Comment: This also applies to existing attributes added to elements whose `prototype` doesn’t provide a property mapping to the attribute, e.g. `<button src="xyz.jpg"></button>`: `button.src` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Only certain standard attributes are directly mapped to properties. This is not the defined behavior for non-standard (custom) attributes.

The forward compatible way of using custom attributes is to prefix them with `data-`.

```
<input ... data-custom_attr="custom_attr_text" ... />
```

Then they become available in HTML5 compliant browsers as:

```
element.dataset.custom_attr
```

But in legacy browsers, you'll still need to use `.getAttribute()`.

Comment: `element.data`? Are you sure you didn't mean [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.dataset)?

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks, that's what I meant. Fixed.