# Strange behavior related with property accessors in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, google-chrome

I have a issue with Chrome and Safari:

Code example:

```js
// Get all links with the same data-test attribute
links = $('[data-test]');

//The issue is here:
// This only works in Chrome, not in safari.
var test = links[0].testProperty;

// This works in Chrome and Safari.
var test2 = $(links[0]).attr('testProperty');

console.log(test)
console.log(test2)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" testProperty="valueTest1" data-test>Test1</a>
<a href="#" testProperty="valueTest2" data-test>Test2</a>
<a href="#" testProperty="valueTest3" data-test>Test3</a>
```

Why Safari does not allow `links[0].testProperty` ?

Comment: The first one doesn't work on chrome too ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010981/javascript-getting-custom-attribute-works-only-with-element-getattributeattrib

Comment: The `testProperty` is an attribute, not a property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15011028/7041168

By standard, you need to use the `date-` before any custom attributes.

And to change the problems, it's best to use `Element.getAttribute("")` property.

Answer (score 0):

`links[0]` is a DOM Element Object, which doesn't have the property `testPropety`.

Neither chrome nor safari would define that property.