# How to add an attribute with a hyphen in the name to a script element?

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like this but I get an "Invalid left-hand side in assignment" error.

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "http://example.com/example.js";
s.data-flix-distributor = "12994";
```

Comment: Pranav's answer below is correct. *Do not assume* that setting a property on a DOM Element object will also set the corresponding attribute. The top answer to this related question is a great overview on how this works in practice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/179125

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In case you want to set a property using [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) then it should be valid identifier other case use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

Refer : [custom attribute works only with element.getAttribute("attribute") but not "element.attribute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010981/custom-attribute-works-only-with-element-getattributeattribute-but-not-elem)

---

To set an attribute to the element use [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method.

```
s.setAttribute('data-flix-distributor', "12994");
```

---

Or update in [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

```
s.dataset['flix-distributor'] = "12994";

// or you can use camelCase to dash-style to use dot notation
s.dataset.flixDistributor = "12994";
```

Refer : [Name conversion in dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset#Name_conversion)

Comment: But you can also just say `s.dataset.flixDistributor`. By the way, what do you mean by "doesn't reflect in the HTML"?

Comment: @torazaburo : you are right - `any ASCII uppercase letter A to Z is transformed into a dash followed by its lowercase counterpart;` ----

Comment: @torazaburo :  sorry it would reflect on the markup, thanks for correcting :)

Comment: Note that the square bracket format with hyphens doesn't work anymore as it throws the following error: `Uncaught DOMException: An invalid or illegal string was specified`

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to set a `data-` attribute is via `element.dataset`. As with styles, there will be automatic conversion from dasherized to camelCase format and vice versa. So

```
s.dataset.flixDistributor = "12994";
```

yields:

```
<div data-flix-distributor="12994"></div>
```