# Parameter passing in JavaScript onclick: this.id versus other attributes

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, onclick

I suspect there is something basic about JavaScript parameter passing that I do not understand.

If I click on this button, I get an 'undefined' message in the alert box.

`<button onclick="play_audio(this.src)" src="foo.m4a">▶</button>`

If I click on this button, the string value is passed properly:

`<button id="foo.m4a" onclick="play_audio(this.id)">▶</button>`

Codepen here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBpMYo

Comment: That’s because there is no `HTMLButtonElement.prototype.src`. `this.getAttribute("src")` would “work”, but use `data-src="foo.m4a"` and `this.dataset.src` instead.

Comment: thanks.  is there any reason i should want ids for my buttons?  i'm trying to keep the markup simple and make it as easy as possible for people to add buttons.

Comment: @Jonathan The only reason is if you want to uniquely identify a specific button, however you can do that a thousand different ways, id is just the fastest DOM lookup with `getElementById()`

Comment: Then I’d recommend using _only_ the `data-src` attribute. Don’t use `onclick`. Instead, add a button, and add its `data` attribute. Then, use event delegation: `document.addEventListener("click", function(e){ if(e.target.matches("button[data-src]")){ playAudio(e.target.dataset.src); } });`.

Comment: Excellent.  Codepen illustrating this approach here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMEpwz

Now I just have to explore playAudio() ...

Comment: My comment should’ve said `play_audio`, the function you’re using, instead of `playAudio`. But it would simply look like `function play_audio(src){new Audio(src).play();}`.

Comment: Related: [Custom attribute works only with `element.getAttribute("attribute")` but not `element.attribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15010981/4642212).

Comment: It works now, using `new Audio(e.target.dataset.audio).play();`

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oMEpwz

Answer (score 1):

A `button` does not have a `src` attribute. However, you can use `this.getAttribute('src')`.

```html
<button src="foo.m4a" onclick="play_audio(this.getAttribute('src'))" >▶</button>
<script>
function play_audio(src){
  console.log("Playing "+src);
}
</script>
```

It is recommended that you use`data-src` (you can use any prefix after `data-`, not necessarily `src`) and `this.dataset.src` instead (you can use the data-* attribute to embed custom data) because it will ensure that your code will not clash with HTML Element attributes for future editions of HTML. See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

```html
<button data-src="foo.m4a" onclick="play_audio(this.dataset.src)" >▶</button>
<script>
    function play_audio(src){
      console.log("Playing "+src);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful answers, folks.  

Why is `this.dataset.src preferred`?

Comment: @Jonathan [Why should I prepend my custom attributes with “data-”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450585/4642212).